# Get substring from a string with specific pattern

Tags: python, tweepy

I am working with twitter links and I have extracted the links from twitter's api.

```
https://twitter.com/shiromiru36/status/1302713597521403904/photo/1
```

The above is an example of links that I have.

I would like to get front part of the link only, I want to delete

```
/photo/1
```

So that I can get

```
https://twitter.com/shiromiru36/status/1302713597521403904
```

Currently I extract the link by counting the number of words that I don't want

```
url = https://twitter.com/shiromiru36/status/1302713597521403904/photo/1
url[:-8]
```

I would like to ask if there is any way to extract the link by finding its own pattern. As the unwanted part is after the 2nd last "/". I am thinking whether I can delete the unwanted part by finding the 2nd last "/" first, and then delete the words after it.

Thank you.

Comment: You could do it using regular-expression. Here is a quick (ugly) solution: `re.search(r'(http[s]?://.*twitter.com/(?:.+/status/)\d+)/', url)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
'/'.join(s.split('/')[:-2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
url = 'https://twitter.com/shiromiru36/status/1302713597521403904/photo/1'
url=(((url[::-1]).split('/',2))[-1])[::-1]
print(url)

https://twitter.com/shiromiru36/status/1302713597521403904
```